# Navicat users - any way to create a variable at the top of a New Query and process on the page?

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I am essentially trying to create a pHp pdo parameter binding equivalent without the use of php at all.

I use Navicat for my sql queries and building and as such am able to do some more interesting things than say just phpmyadmin.

I have one query in particular which takes a date value and applies it to (literally) 14 if, where, and group by statements. I would like to essentially create a variable at the top of the page, say:

```
:date
```

then within the query, apply the variable say:

```
WHERE date_inserted > :date
```

I believe this could be done in a stored procedure but I'd like to just keep as a query (within query editor)

### edit - example:

In php, you can create a prepared sql query using pdo like the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE field1 = :field1 AND datefield <= :date1 AND datefield2 >= :date1 AND datefield3 > :date1");

$stmt->bindParam(':field1', $somevariable);
$stmt->bindParam(':date1', $somedate);
$stmt->execute();
```

I want to do the exact same thing with sql only (using navicat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another answer since you don't want to use join

```
SET @@session.var = 'some_value'; 
select * from table where field = @@session.var
```

Have not tested but I read from here

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,127011,127796#msg-127796

I think the variable will be preserved until the connection is closed and recreated.

**Edit:** OP found the rest of the answer. Editing in as requested.

You can set variables within an SQL call using:

```
SET @variablename = [value]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: didn't work for me but was a good shot - i'll toy around with it some given the error returned is: 1193 - Unknown system variable 'var'

Comment: I found the answer, similar to yours but no session variables or mentions

Comment: if you update your answer, i'll go ahead and give you the check since you pointed me in the right direction to start.

Answer (score 3):

After looking further into my own question, found you can set variables within a sql call using:

> SET @variablename = [value]

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the whole query? I think a derived table might work if it is a SELECT statement.

A simple example would be to start with this

```
select * from table where field = 'somedate'
```

Change it to this

```
select table.* from (select 'somedate' q)q, table where field = q.q
```

So `q` is your derived table of a single row and single field and `q.q` is your field.

I really don't know anything more helpful without seeing more of the statement.

By the way, I know nothing about PHP, phpmyadmin, Navicat or stored procedure. Only self taught MySQL.

Comment: not looking to do any joins. Just didn't know if it were possible to create variables. Think of it as a PHP prepared statement with bound variables. I will provide an example above but the entire query is very long and dont want to post for security sake

Comment: @JM4: Just edited that I know nothing of PHP, but I know of Java prepared statements. I will add another answer for session variables.